# Securing user registration endpoint

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

The whole API is built on top django-restframework and django-oauth2-toolkit. I want to add API endpoint which will allow client applications to register users.

So, if I want to register user I have next options:

- I have to authenticate before `POSTing` request (does not make sense at all)
- to open `api/users/register` to everyone (is not secure).

What I want to do, is to grant access to this endpoint based on oauth2's `client_id` and `client_secret`. Is there straightforward way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#oauth2authentication - Are you sure this is what you want? Why not just HTTPS?

Comment: HTTPS will be enabled by default (it won't prevent access to api/users/register). If I leave registration endpoint opened, anyone can easily create a bunch of users through API (just by using simple bash script)

Comment: I suppose your API is being consumed by known clients then.

Comment: Exactly. And I want to give access to registration only to them